# Create and Align Node Labels, then Add Square Brackets and Label Under Nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have the below code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc,arrows,backgrounds, shapes.misc,snakes}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)[fill, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = blue, label={$\dot{x}$}] (xdot) {};
\node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = yellow, right=0.15cm of xdot, label={$\dot{y}$}] (ydot) {};
\node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = red, right=0.15cm of ydot, label={$\dot{z}$}] (zdot) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was hoping to align the three labels for the `nodes`, as well as put brackets around them and $\textbf{X}$ underneath but am not sure how to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\strut` into your node label content.

[image: strut]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc,arrows,backgrounds, shapes.misc,snakes}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)[fill, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = blue, label={$\strut \dot{x}$}] (xdot) {};
\node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = yellow, right=0.15cm of xdot, label={$\strut \dot{y}$}] (ydot) {};
\node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = red, right=0.15cm of ydot, label={$\strut  \dot{z}$}] (zdot) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

An addendum to place nodes label below and put square brackets around them:

[image: strut 2]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc,arrows,backgrounds, shapes.misc,snakes}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0)[fill, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = blue, label={[name=X]below:$\strut \dot{x}$}] (xdot) {};
        \node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = yellow, right=0.15cm of xdot, label={[name=Y]below:$\strut \dot{y}$}] (ydot) {};
        \node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = red, right=0.15cm of ydot, label={[name=Z]below:$\strut  \dot{z}$}] (zdot) {};
        \node[left=-5pt of X]{$[$};
        \node[right=-5pt of Z]{$]$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT 2

Trying to fit OP's demand:

[image: strut v3]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc,arrows,backgrounds, shapes.misc,snakes}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0)[fill, rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = blue, label={[name=X]above:$\strut \dot{x}$}] (xdot) {};
        \node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = yellow, right=0.15cm of xdot, label={[name=Y]above:$\strut \dot{y}$}] (ydot) {};
        \node at (0,0)[fill,rounded corners, rectangle, minimum height=6cm, fill = red, right=0.15cm of ydot, label={[name=Z]above:$\strut  \dot{z}$}] (zdot) {};
        \draw[thick] ($(xdot.north)+(-8pt,0)$) --++(-5pt,0) |- ($(xdot.south)+(-8pt,0)$);
        \draw[thick] ($(zdot.north)+(8pt,0)$) --++(5pt,0) |- ($(zdot.south)+(8pt,0)$);
        \node[below= 0pt of ydot]{\textbf{X}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to add the label under the three nodes and/or how to put square brackets around them?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant square brackets around the length of the nodes, leaving the labels at the top of the three nodes, and one more label at the bottom, centred between the three.

Comment: I tried to fit your needs. Please, if it's not what you want, provide a sketch of what you're looking for.

Comment: I appreciate it and you've been helpful, I am trying to draw something that looks like this https://imgur.com/a/0EGV1G5

Comment: OK, so what I provided is OK, at this particular moment (except for the dot on the X, which you can add without any problem). I suggest that you work on it a bit and come later with another question if needed, linking this one to provide context. And you may accept my answer if it suits you well for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124084/discussion-between-sebglav-and-aw27).